# script not importing the file for working in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

the html file does not seem to be importing the javascript function particle() to upload i have the script in another file  and i am importing it to my html file but it does not work , it might be some basic error i just cant figure it out here !
if you could fix this code i would really appreciate it .

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var particles = {};
var particleIndex = 0;
var particleNum = 15;

// set canvas size
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// add canvas to body
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// style the canvas
c.fillStyle = "black";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function Particle() {
this.x = canvas.width / 2;
this.y = canvas.height / 2;
this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
this.gravity = 0.3;
particleIndex++;
particles[particleIndex] = this;
this.id = particleIndex;
this.life = 0;


this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
}

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
this.x += this.vx;
this.y += this.vy;


if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
    this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
}

this.life++;
if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
    delete particles[this.id];
}

c.fillStyle = this.color;
//c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
c.beginPath();
c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.fill();
};

setInterval(function() {
//normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
    new Particle();
}

// c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

for (var i in particles) {
    particles[i].draw();
}
}, 30);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>disturbed</title>

  <script src="toto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        Particle();
    };
  </script>


</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function runParticles () {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var particles = {};
  var particleIndex = 0;
  var particleNum = 15;

  // set canvas size
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  // add canvas to body
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // style the canvas
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  function Particle() {
  this.x = canvas.width / 2;
  this.y = canvas.height / 2;
  this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.gravity = 0.3;
  particleIndex++;
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  this.id = particleIndex;
  this.life = 0;


  this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


  this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
  }

  Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;


  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  }

  this.life++;
  if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete particles[this.id];
  }

  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  //c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  c.fill();
  };

  setInterval(function() {
  //normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
  c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
      new Particle();
  }

  // c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

  for (var i in particles) {
      particles[i].draw();
  }
  }, 30);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>disturbed</title>

  <script src="toto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = () => runParticles();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Remove this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    Particle();
};
```

Comment: but i want to use the script with windows.onload function

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: Just wrap your  JS in a function and call it